# Divide a value based on another cell value and split it eventually by the divisor from where an another cell is matched with another cell value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a formula to divide a value by an another cell value and split the value eventually. This works fine but it splits from the starting month.

My current formula:

```
=IF(COLUMN()-COLUMN($F5)<$I5, IF(COLUMN()-COLUMN($J5)<$F5, $I5/$F5, 0), "")
```

*Now split using this formula*

| REVENUES | Start Month | End Month | Start Month2 | Duration | GBP | INR | Total Project Value | Apr | May | Jun | Jul | Aug | Sep | Oct | Nov | Dec | Jan | Feb | Mar |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Project 1 | 01-07-2023 | 14-10-2023 | Jul | 3 | 2000 | 200000 | 200000 | 66667 | 66667 | 66667 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Project 2 | 01-06-2023 | 14-10-2023 | Jun | 4 | 1000 | 100000 | 100000 | 25000 | 25000 | 25000 | 25000 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Project 3 | 01-05-2023 | 14-10-2023 | May | 5 | 1000 | 100000 | 100000 | 20000 | 20000 | 20000 | 20000 | 20000 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

However, I have to split the value eventually where the value in the "Start Month2" is matched with the Header months like in below shared the table.

*Need a formula to Split like the below*

| REVENUES | Start Month | End Month | Start Month2 | Duration | GBP | INR | Total Project Value | Apr | May | Jun | Jul | Aug | Sep | Oct | Nov | Dec | Jan | Feb | Mar |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Project 1 | 01-07-2023 | 14-10-2023 | Jul | 3 | 2000 | 200000 | 200000 |  |  |  | 66667 | 66667 | 66667 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Project 2 | 01-06-2023 | 14-10-2023 | Jun | 4 | 1000 | 100000 | 100000 |  |  | 25000 | 25000 | 25000 | 25000 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Project 3 | 01-05-2023 | 14-10-2023 | May | 5 | 1000 | 100000 | 100000 |  | 20000 | 20000 | 20000 | 20000 | 20000 |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Comment: What do you mean with " I have to split the value eventually where the value in the "Start Month2" is matched with the Header months like in below shared the table"? It would be useful to get an example of your intended result.

Comment: @karl, Thanks, now i edited the post, please look on it., i hope, this is useful.

Comment: In which range is your initial data to better understand your formula?

Answer (score 0):

Couple of changes to make this work:

1. change the column headers to date values:
2. change the end month date to a date value and to the first of the month

Use this formula (example for cell I2 in my image):

```
=IF(AND(I$1>=$B2,I$1<$C2),$H2/$E2,"")
```

Drag the formula down and across.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is the one what i'm expecting, however it would be better to match the month by the string like "Jul", "Aug", because, somewhere the value is not split equally by the Duration, that is, it is calculating the each days.